How to interpret the result of a bootstrapped multiple regression?
My data didn't have normally distributed residuals, so I have used bootstrapping to run a multiple regression analysis.
My model is the following: independent variables A and B predict the dependent variable C.
Variable A and B are the average scores on multiple Likert items used to assess personality traits, variable C is the average score on multiple Likert items used to assess life satisfaction.
The results of my analysis in JASP are the following:



Model Summary - C













Model
R
R²
Adjusted R²
RMSE
R² Change
F Change
df1
df2
p


H_0
0.000
0.000
0.000
1.636
0.000

0
414



H_1
0.145
0.021
0.016
1.622
0.021
4.438
2
412
0.012






Coefficients



















95% CI



Model

Unstandardized
Standard Error
Standardized
t
p
Lower
Upper


H_0
(Intercept)
6.158x10^-16
0.080

7.669×10-15
1.000
-0.158
0.158


H_1
(Intercept)
5.594x10^-16
0.080

7.024x10^-15
1.000
-0.157
1.57



B
0.023
0.093
0.013
0.246
0.806
-0.160
0.205



A
-0.283
0.098
-0.149
-2.900
0.004
-0.475
-0.091






Bootstrap Coefficients

















95% CI



Model

Unstandardized
Bias
Standard Error
p*
Lower
Upper


H_0
(Intercept)
0.002
0.002
0.080
0.974
-0.169
0.147


H_1
(Intercept)
0.002
6.162x10^-4
0.080
0.981
-0.166
0.148



B
0.023
-0.001
0.084
0.780
-0.147
0.185



A
-0.278
0.005
0.096
0.002
-0.476
-0.099



I am confused on how to interpret these results and how to report them. If there is any part of the results missing that I should also provide, let me know.
What I gather is the following:
Model Summary:

Without Bootstrapping, my model explains 2% of variance (R²) with a statistically significant p-value of 0.012.

Coefficients:

The impact of B is negligible (confidence interval includes 0, p-value is >.05)
A's impact is significant (confidence interval does not include 0, p-value is <.05)

Bootstrap Coefficients:

Essentially the same as in Coefficients, but with slightly different values.

Do I understand it correctly that the Bootstrap Coefficients table essentially just replaces the Coefficients table, that my bootstrapped model explains 2% of the variance, and that I can go ahead and report as I would report a normal multiple regression analysis using the values in Model Summary - C and Bootstrap Coefficients, with the added information that it's the result of a 5000 replicates bootstrapping?

Welcome to Cross Validated! There's much positive to be said for bootstrapping as a way to validate a model-building scheme. I was wondering, however, just what you meant by saying "My data was not normally distributed, so I have used bootstrapping to run a multiple regression analysis." Was it that the outcome values themselves weren't normally distributed, or that the residuals around the model predictions weren't normally distributed? Normality of the outcome values isn't necessary at all; see this page among others.

You are right that bootstrapping didn't change much. But see @EdM's comment.  Also, "negligible" is not synonymous with "not significant".  Nor is  Since you haven't told us what A, B, C, $H_0$ or $H_1$ are, or how they are measured, it's hard to say more.  However, the fact that $R^2$ is only 2% and that nothing changed much in the bootstrap model is some sign that neither A nor B did much. A is significant, but it appears to be small (although, again, we'd need to know what it is and how it's measured to really say).

Thank you.
I have updated the post (I was indeed talking about the residuals, I ran the Shapiro Wilk test which was highly significant, and the QQ-Plot had a significant s-shape) and added some information about the variables.
I did not define H_0 and H_1 in JASP. I know I can do a hierarchical regression by telling it to add model terms to the null model, but I didn't do that. So I unfortunately don't know how to say more about H_0/H_1.

The answer depends on which flavor of bootstrap is implemented in JASP. It looks like the reports for the bootstrap estimates are based simply on fitting the same model to multiple bootstrapped re-samples from your data set. The "unstandardized" bootstrapped coefficients would be the averages over all those models; the "bias" would be the difference between the bootstrap averages and the original model coefficients; the standard errors and confidence intervals would presumably be based on the distributions of coefficient estimates among those models. You need to check the help pages for JASP to be sure, however, as this page suggests that there might be some confusion on how bootstrapping is done and reported in JASP.
There is a different use of bootstrapping in this context that can be even more informative. Besides fitting the model to multiple bootstrapped samples, the "optimism bootstrap" evaluates the performance of each of the models on the full original data set. The average difference between the performance of each model on its corresponding bootstrap sample and the full data sample then provides an estimate of the "optimism" of the modeling process, due to overfitting the data. See this page or this page, for example. It's possible that JASP is reporting that type of bootstrap instead, but you would have to check the documentation.
All that said, Peter From summarized the results pretty well in his comment. There might be a "statistically significant" association between A and outcome, but assessing its practical significance depends on applying your knowledge of the subject matter: what your measurements of predictors and outcomes represent in practice.
In terms of reporting the results, it might be simplest just to report the original model in your main test as it stands, with a statement that the estimates were essentially the same when based on 5000 bootstrap re-samples. Then show the report of the bootstrapped models in supplementary material.
Finally, with this number of observations you might consider  a more complex model. First, your model assumes that each of A and B has a strictly linear association with outcome. It can be helpful to relax that assumption by fitting those predictors flexibly, as with a regression spline. Second, you might include an interaction term between predictors A and B, to relax the implicit assumption of your model that the association of each predictor with outcome is independent of the level of the other.
